# Hibernate pulando sequencia do id

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, yeoman

Eu gerei um projeto pelo `JHipster` que usa `Java`, `Spring` e `Hibernate` no backend, criei uma classe da seguinte forma:

Liquibase:

```
 <changeSet id="20160504131602" author="jhipster">
        <createTable tableName="grupo">
            <column name="id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="${autoIncrement}">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="nm_grupo" type="varchar(35)">
                <constraints unique="true" nullable="false" />
            </column>
 </createTable>
```

Domain:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "grupo")
@Document(indexName = "grupo")
public class Grupo implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 35)
    @Column(name = "nm_grupo", length = 35, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String nmGrupo;
```

A questão é que quando mando salvar um registro (Classe rest):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/grupos",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<Grupo> createGrupo(@Valid @RequestBody Grupo grupo) throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug("REST request to save Grupo : {}", grupo);
        if (grupo.getId() != null) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().headers(HeaderUtil.createFailureAlert("grupo", "idexists", "A new grupo cannot already have an ID")).body(null);
        }
        Grupo result = grupoService.save(grupo);
        return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/grupos/" + result.getId()))
            .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert("grupo", result.getId().toString()))
            .body(result);
    }
```

Que por sua vez chama a função **save** da classe de implementação:

```
public Grupo save(Grupo grupo) {
        log.debug("Request to save Grupo : {}", grupo);
        Grupo result = grupoRepository.save(grupo);
        grupoSearchRepository.save(result);
        return result;
    }
```

Salvando o objeto fisicamente no banco:

```
public interface GrupoRepository extends JpaRepository<Grupo,Long> {

}
```

Se eu mandar salvar um objeto com um nome já cadastrado no banco de dados o hibernate retorna o erro:

> ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "grupo_nm_grupo_key"**

Esse erro eu já tratei, porém quando eu salvo um novo registro o código gerado para o id é pulado em +1, ficando assim um id perdido.

Ex:

1. Salve o grupo: **A** (id gerado: 1)
2. Salve o grupo: **A** (erro pois já existe valor no banco)
3. Salve o grupo: **AS** (id gerado: 3)

Perceba que perdi o id 2.

Alguém sabe uma forma elegante de resolver esse problema, sem precisar criar uma nova consulta antes do save para verificar se o nome já foi cadastrado?

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente esse Identificador está sendo gerado pelo *backend* (Postgresql).

Esse fenômeno acontece pois as `SEQUENCES` em Postgresql são resistentes a `ROLLBACKs` dentro de transações.

Provavelmente o `autoIncrement` da coluna `id`, está usando um objeto de `SEQUENCE` no banco de dados:

```
<column name="id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="${autoIncrement}">
    <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
</column>
```

`SEQUENCES` são destinadas a geração de identificadores únicos - não necessariamente identificadores que são estritamente sequenciais!

Você não deve usar `SEQUENCES` quando você estiver precisando de uma sequência sem intervalos entre os identificadores.

Por exemplo, as `SEQUENCES` garantem que se dois clientes tentarem obter simultanêamente um valor de uma sequência (usando `nextval()`), cada cliente receberá um valor sequêncial diferente. Se um desses clientes abortar posteriormente a sua transação usando um `ROLLBACK`, o valor de sequência que foi gerado para esse cliente vai se perder e isso criará uma lacuna na sequência.

Segue exemplo ilustrando o funcionamento de uma `SEQUENCE` dentro de uma transação:

```
-- Criação do Objeto de SEQUENCE
CREATE SEQUENCE sq_teste;

-- Inicializa a Sequence
SELECT nextval('sq_teste');

-- Verifica o valor da sequencia antes de entrar na transação
SELECT currval('sq_teste'); -- ID=1

BEGIN;
SELECT nextval('sq_teste'); -- ID=2
SELECT nextval('sq_teste'); -- ID=3
SELECT nextval('sq_teste'); -- ID=4
ROLLBACK;

-- Verifica o valor da sequencia após ROLLBACK da transação
SELECT currval('sq_teste'); -- ID: 4!

--- fim-de-arquivo ---
```

Repare que mesmo apoś o `ROLLBACK` o valor da sequência não retornou ao que era antes do inicio da transação.

Agora a dúvida é minha: Por que os IDs cadastrados precisam respeitar uma sequência crescente sem intervalos ?

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 0):

Infelizmente não encontrei em nenhum lugar, nem na documentação do hibernate uma forma de fazer isso de forma automática.

Tive que criar a consulta na mão antes do insert para verificar se o nome já existia na base.